# Why won't Rails render my partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to DRY up my views a bit by turning multiple nested elements into partials that yield blocks. I decided to start with a simple example to get going.

In my view:

```
= render :partial => "../snippets/indented_divs", :locals => {:width => 12} do 
  %p foo
```

In `app/views/snippets/_indented_divs.html.haml`:

```
%div.col-sm-1
%div{:class => "col-sm-#{width-2}"}
  = yield
%div.col-sm-1
```

The error:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

I've seen discussion of this error, but it relates to people trying to implicitly convert an ActiveModel-compatible object into a partial. I'm not. I'm trying to call my partial directly.

What's going on?

**UPDATE**

BTW, the problem is clearly with yielding the block, not finding the partial, because when I update the view to not take the block...

```
= render :partial => "/_snippets/indented_divs", :locals => {:width => 12} 
%p foo
```

...I get...

```
<div class='col-sm-1'></div>
<div class='col-sm-10'></div>
<div class='col-sm-1'></div>
<p>foo</p>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out I can make this work with:

```
  = render :layout => "/snippets/indented_divs", :locals => {:width => 12} do
    %p foo
```

But as I'm actually rendering a partial here, it'd still be good to know why passing a block to a rendered partial didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing, the problem might be in locating the snippets directory

```
= render "/_snippets/indented_divs", :width => 12 do 
%p foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `undercore`:

```
= render :partial => "snippets/indented_divs", :locals => {:width => 12} do 
%p foo
```

UPDATE:

add `underscore` to the file, it should be `_indented_divs.html.haml`. Partial should always start with `underscore`.

```
app/views/snippets/_indented_divs.html.haml:
```

Comment: thx but that wasn't it -- got the same error with ` "../snippets/indented"` (and corresponding change to the partial's filename)

Comment: Oh, add underscore to your file. I updated my answer. Partial always starts with `_` `underscore`.

Comment: sorry, yes, thx -- i had fixed that locally but not in my stackoverflow question text -- i've fixed my question text now -- the render helper definitely finds the partial, as it renders the partial when i don't try to pass it a block -- the problem is something to do with passing it a block